# Bootstrap rows and columns not working properly inside for each loop

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I tried to use bootstrap row and columns classes inside a for each loop and some extra spaces are displayed as unexpected.

First I used the following code and it worked well.

```
<table border="0" id="myTable" class="table" >  
        <thead border-bottom="0">  
            <tr>
                <th border-bottom="0" style="display: none;">Gem</th> 
                <th border-bottom="0" style="display: none;">Name</th>
            </tr>  
        </thead>  
        <tbody>
            @foreach(App\GemStone::where('active',TRUE)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get() as $gemStone)

            <div class="row"> 
            <tr>
            <td style="display: none;" >{{$gemStone->created_at}}</td>


                <td>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div align="center"> 
                                <img alt="Gem Stone Pic" src="{{route('get_image',['id' => $gemStone->id])}} " class="img-circle img-responsive">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <h3><b><a href="#">{{$gemStone->type->type}}</a></b></h3>
                            @if($gemStone->shop->user->id == Auth::user()->id)
                            <a href="{{route('view_update_gem_stone',['id' => $gemStone->id])}}">[Edit]</a><br>
                            @endif
                            {{$gemStone->size->size}}<br>
                            LKR: {{$gemStone->price}}<br>
                            <div> 
                                {{$gemStone->description}}<br>
                                {{$gemStone->created_at}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3"> free space of 3 cols </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">free space of 3 cols </div>
                </td>        


            </tr>
            </div>

            @endforeach
        </tbody>  
    </table>
```

[above code gave a view like this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfpos.png)  In order to use the free space marked in the picture, I tried adding another column by creating another `<td> ... </td>` inside `<tr> </tr>` using `$counter` variable as below.

```
        <table border="0" id="myTable" class="table" >  
        <thead border-bottom="0">  
            <tr>
                <th border-bottom="0" style="display: none;">Gem</th> 
                <th border-bottom="0" style="display: none;">Name</th> 
                <th border-bottom="0" style="display: none;">Name</th>
            </tr>  
        </thead>  
        <tbody>
            <?php $count = 0 ?>
            @foreach(App\GemStone::where('active',TRUE)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get() as $gemStone)
            <?php $count = $count + 1 ?>
            @if($count % 2)
            <tr>
                <div class="row">
                    <td style="display: none;" >{{$gemStone->created_at}}</td> 
                    @endif                  
                    <td>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div align="center"> 
                                <img alt="Gem Stone Pic" src="{{route('get_image',['id' => $gemStone->id])}} " class="img-circle img-responsive">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <h3><b><a href="#">{{$gemStone->type->type}}</a></b></h3>
                            @if($gemStone->shop->user->id == Auth::user()->id)
                            <a href="{{route('view_update_gem_stone',['id' => $gemStone->id])}}">[Edit]</a><br>
                            @endif
                            {{$gemStone->size->size}}<br>
                            LKR: {{$gemStone->price}}<br>
                            <div> 
                                {{$gemStone->description}}<br>
                                {{$gemStone->created_at}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>        
                @if(!($count % 2))
            </div>
        </tr>
        @endif
        @endforeach
        @if($count%2)
        <td>extra cell when odd</td>
    </div>
</tr>
@endif
```

[Result looked like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KnwC.png) which is unexpected. I tried changing the place of `<div class='row'>`  and `<div class = 'col-s6'>`in several ways, but nothing worked. And I couldn't  really find a mistake in the code as well . It would be grateful if someone can point where I go wrong while using the columns and row classes.

And I'm using jquery datatables to get the table view.

Comment: That's because you're jamming elements between table elements that shouldn't be there, i.e. the only permitted parent of a `td` is a `tr`. When you start using the Bootstrap grid system outside of it's intended usage undesired effects are to be expected. From the looks of it, your table is unnecessary and is attempting to do what the grid system can accomplish on it's own.

Comment: do not use tables for layout!

Comment: You can get table like behavior by JUST using bootstrap rows and cols

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic

Comment: If this is what you're talking about have you [**attempted the following**](https://datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap)?

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake.. why dnt you assign the classes directly to the tr and td? `<tr class="row"> <td class="col-xx-xx"></td></tr>`

Comment: @ajc your suggestion did the trick. May be you can post it as an answer that I can accept it.

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake, use divs for layout; will make you life easier, and your software better.

Comment: Do you really know what "col-md-4" means if, your using bootstrap of course?

Comment: ... in that case, Why you can't have your "searching capability over data" whitout a table layout??

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake when you finish your code with the table layout, try to see the result in a mobile device. Also, try to spend some time learning bootstrap. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the bootstrap classes to your table elements, instead of adding additional div elements.

```
<table>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="col-md-4">1</td>
    <td class="col-md-4">2</td>
    <td class="col-md-4">3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```